# x__icontains match 2 values

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to make a call to python from javascript and I want to match 2 values with __icontains.

This is what I currently have

```
fetchData(value) {
    axiox.get('/api/beats.json/', { 
            params: { 
                name__icontains: value, 
                fields: 'field1', 'field2'
            }
        })
        .then(response => (this.beats = response.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

But I need to pass 2 values, so it would become something like this:

```
fetchData(value1, value2) {
    axiox.get('/api/beats.json/', { 
            params: { 
                name__icontains: [value1, value2]
                fields: 'field1, field2'
            }
        })
        .then(response => (this.beats = response.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Array syntax doesn't work, this `name__icontains: 'x, y'` neither.
How can I get this to work?

Comment: Which API is this? Does the API support this?

Comment: It's django-filter, I noticed now by playing in the url, adding 2 'name__icontains' works, but I'm passing it as params in this case..

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/search/